# Max length of the database name in Mongodb 4

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to connect (from a asp.net core 3) and insert a document to a new database that does not exist on the mongo.
in the below command I will get an exception.

```
   _context.account.InsertOne(new MongoModels.account
            {
                Description = "any description",
                Name = "any name"
            });
```

and this is the exception:

```
Command insert failed: Database name myapp-account-Processing-Development is too long.  Max database name length is 38 bytes..
```

based on the [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/limits/#naming-restrictions) "Database names cannot be empty and must have fewer than 64 characters." my name is not even close to that length ?

and why the exception is saying that the max length can be 38 byte ?

Comment: Do you use MongoDB Atlas? [Atlas M0 (Free Tier), M2, and M5 Limitations](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations): *Namespaces and Database Names: M0 Free Tier and M2/M5 shared cluster namespaces are limited to 95 bytes. **Database names are limited to 38 bytes**.*

Comment: I think you are right ... this is a question I have asked out devops ... but I guess we are using one of those versions ... other than that it does not make sense to get that exception.